# Getting the shape of nested arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

I am wondering whether there is a function that would compute the shape of nested arrays.

```
 multiArr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
 size(multiArr)
 #Out > (2,)
```

I am looking for the output (2,4)

I am aware that if you convert it to a matrix you could get this output,

```
 mat = reshape(hcat(multiArr...),size(multiArr)[1],size(multiArr[1])[1])
 size(mat)
 #Out > (2,4)
```

But wondering if there is a way to get the inner dimensions of nested arrays ?

Comment: size(mat[1]) should do

Comment: An array of arrays is not the same as a 2D array.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array

Comment: I think you are trying to treat a vector of vectors as a matrix, and it doesn't really make sense. What should your hypothetical function do with `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]]`? Or some longer array with more dissimilar members? If you are using a vector of identically sized vectors, you _should_ use a matrix instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just broadcast `size` over inner arrays:

```
julia> size.(multiArr)
2-element Vector{Tuple{Int64}}:
 (4,)
 (4,)
```

You will get a `Vector` of sizes because of course each of those can be different.